# Automatically including source files into Visual Studio 15

Tags: c++, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2015

Overview:

I am wanting to allow visual studio 15 to automatically add an existing source file after I generate them.

Full explanation:

I am currently generating a lot of new .h and .cpp files with other tools outside of the IDE using bat scripts and such but needing to use them within the IDE to integrate with the project. As such I would be great if there was a a way to allow VS to add these source files automatically after they are generated without having to add them manually.

The files are always generated into the same given folder path if that helps.

Comment: Do the files always have the same name? If so, you could add an `<Include />` or `<Compile />` element to the MSBuild project file that references a file that is generated later by your process. If VS won't be running then you could just edit the MSBuild file as an XML file using a DOM library. If VS is running then you'll want to use DTE (VS's COM automation/extensibility API) to alter the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the project with a [CMake](http://cmake.org) script. When you run your batch file, you could have it re-invoke CMake to update the project with the new sources. If you are generating files, especially if you can't predict the names in advance, you will likely want to use the CMake's [`file(GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/file.html) command.